# Call one app's view from another in Marionette

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I have an **IdentificationView** that has to call a method of another view in different app:

```
var NameAndIdentificationView = Application.Views.ItemView.extend({
    loadMailingAddressView: function() {
                //call to mailing address view method setAddress() from here
    }
});
```

Now my **MailingAddressView** is something like this:

```
var MailingAddressView= Application.Views.ItemView.extend({
    setAddress: function(address) {
        if (address != null) {
            // this.autoCompleteBox.data('inputData') = address;
            ProWeb.EXTRACTED_ADDRESS = address;
            this.model.set('mailingAddress', address);
        }
    }
});
```

I would like to know what is the way to call a method of one view from another. Please provide suggestions.

**EDIT:**

This is how my application has been setup:

1. First **App** is called.
2. Then the **Controller** is called.
3. From within the **Controller**, **View** is called and intialized.

So from within my **NameIdentificationView**, I'm calling the **MailingAddress** app that in turn controls all the process of calling the controller and it's view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it many ways using event channel,triggering and listening events on shared model, the simpler way of doing this is using Bsckbone events.

Trigger a event in caller

```
loadMailingAddressView: function () {
                //call to mailing address view method setAddress() from here
             Backbonw.trigger('setAddress')
})
```

and listen in callee's initalize

```
    var MailingAddressView = Application.Views.ItemView.extend({

    initialize: function() {
        Backbone.on('setAddress', this.setAddress)
    },
    setAddress: function(address) {
        if (address != null) {
            // this.autoCompleteBox.data('inputData') = address;
            ProWeb.EXTRACTED_ADDRESS = address;
            this.model.set('mailingAddress', address);
        }
    },
});
```

make sure callee View is initialized by the time you trigger event

Comment: how do I initialize the MailingAddressView here?

Comment: just like other views, can you be more specific?

Comment: I've edited my question to be more specific. Please let me know if I'm still not clear.

Comment: i am confused, i don't know what is app and controller it will be. so just initialize  MailingAddressView before loadMailingAddressView and you are good to go

Comment: Hey @ezpura, that worked, thanks!
Just one more thing, I want to pass on parameters to the setAddress() method during the trigger. Can I do that?